# Как сделать раскрывающееся и скрывающееся меню на js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, меню

Есть скрытое меню. Раскрывается оно по клику на кнопке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике на кнопку, блоку меню присваивается класс `menu_active`. Меню открывается и скрывается только при клике на кнопку `<button>`.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.menu-button').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_active {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 80px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.menu-button {
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(81, 11, 186, 0.1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(81, 11, 186, 0.1);
  height: 80px;
  width: 70px;
}

.menu-button-line {
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #89a9eb;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu-button navbar_menu-button">
   <span class="menu-button-line"></span>
   <span class="menu-button-line"></span>
   <span class="menu-button-line"></span>
</button>

<nav class="menu_nav">
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Каталог скинали</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Этапы работ</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Примеры работ</a>
</nav>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на пункты меню (Главная, Каталог скинали ... ) меню скрывалось и кнопка менялась на `Х`?

Comment: проверка клика на меню, если да, то скрывайте меню

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь:

```js
$('.burger, .menu_nav>a').click(function() {
  $('.burger').toggleClass('open');
  $('.menu_nav').toggleClass('menu_nav_active');
});
```

```css
/*Меню*/

.menu_nav {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu_nav_active {
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu_nav>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menu_nav>a:hover {
  background: deepskyblue;
}


/*Иконка*/

.burger {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 33px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.burger-brick {
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.open .burger-brick:first-child {
  margin-top: 14px;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.open .burger-brick:last-child {
  margin-top: -14px;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}

.open .middle {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="burger-brick"></div>
  <div class="burger-brick middle"></div>
  <div class="burger-brick"></div>
</div>
<nav class="menu_nav">
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Каталог скинали</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Этапы работ</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Примеры работ</a>
</nav>
```